# Passing initial into Django's ModelFormSet

Tags: django

I have a model formset that I need to pass the keyword `initial` in to (to have some initial values in the formset, such as date set to today).

As far as I can tell, the queryset argument (which defaults to `YourModel.objects.all()`) overrides this ability for initial empty forms to be created.

I specified the queryset as: `YourModel.objects.none()`, which prevents it from filling in the formset with entries from the database, but I still can't figure out how to pass initial in effectively.

Do I need to subclass a method from `ModelForm`?

Comment: You want to change a particular instance of the model, but you don't want to display its existing values and instead display different initial values?

Answer (score 10):

You are passing an empty queryset to ModelFormset.

```
ExampleModelFormSet = modelformset_factory(ExampleModel, extra=2)
formset = ExampleModelFormSet(queryset=ExampleModel.objects.none(),
                          initial=[{'name': 'Some Name'},
                                   {'name': 'Another Name'}])
```

which is indeed the way to achieve what you want. It makes sense to pass an empty queryset, else initial values will override the model's database value.

And if I suppose, you are passing a non-empty queryset, and yet want your extra forms to be filled will initial values, you can override the `Formset`.

```
from django.forms.models import modelformset_factory  
ExampleFormset = modelformset_factory(OpenIDProfile, extra=3)

class myFormset(ExampleFormset):

    def _construct_form(self, i, **kwargs):
        """
        Instantiates and returns the i-th form instance in a formset.
        """
        if self.is_bound and i < self.initial_form_count():
            pk_key = "%s-%s" % (self.add_prefix(i), self.model._meta.pk.name)
            pk = self.data[pk_key]
            pk_field = self.model._meta.pk
            pk = pk_field.get_db_prep_lookup('exact', pk)
            if isinstance(pk, list):
                pk = pk[0]
            kwargs['instance'] = self._existing_object(pk)
        if i < self.initial_form_count() and not kwargs.get('instance'):
            kwargs['instance'] = self.get_queryset()[i]

        defaults = {'auto_id': self.auto_id, 'prefix': self.add_prefix(i)}
        if self.data or self.files:
            defaults['data'] = self.data
            defaults['files'] = self.files
        # Check to confirm we are not overwriting the database value.
        if not i in range(self.initial_form_count()) and self.initial:
            try:
                defaults['initial'] = self.initial[i - self.initial_form_count()]
            except IndexError:
                pass
        # Allow extra forms to be empty.
        if i >= self.initial_form_count():
            defaults['empty_permitted'] = True
        defaults.update(kwargs)
        form = self.form(**defaults)
        self.add_fields(form, i)        
        return form
```

Note: `initial` is list of dicts. Its desirable to have items in list exactly equal to the number of extra.

Comment: One trick that got me here is that you have to set extra greater than or equal to the number of elements in your initial data. I know it is in your answer, but I thought it was worth highlighting.

Answer (score 9):

New in Django 1.4  ...if you set initial on a modelformset it now only applies to the 'extra' forms, not those bound to instances from the queryset:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#providing-initial-values

So the various hacks above are no longer necessary and using initial is the answer.

Answer (score 6):

The best way I've found to do this is to just manually adjust the formset object's "extra" attribute after initialization.  This has been tested and works in Django 1.9.

```
ExampleModelFormSet = modelformset_factory(ExampleModel, extra=1)
formset = ExampleModelFormSet(initial=[{'name': 'Some Name'},
                                       {'name': 'Another Name'}])
formset.extra = 3
```

This will spit out 3 forms (2 prepopulated and 1 blank).

If you want something more dynamic (e.g. `initial` is a var calculated somewhere else), you can do something like this:

```
ExampleModelFormSet = modelformset_factory(ExampleModel, extra=1)
formset = ExampleModelFormSet(initial=initial)
formset.extra += len(initial)
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Without passing a queryset, this is messed

Answer (score 4):

It is  still possible to pass initial to a ModelFormSet.

```
from django.forms.models import modelformset_factory
from example.models import ExampleModel

ExampleModelFormSet = modelformset_factory(ExampleModel)
formset = ExampleModelFormSet(initial=[{'name': 'Some Name'},
                                       {'name': 'Another Name'}])
```

If this is not what your after, can you explain your question more.

*EDIT:*

```
ExampleModelFormSet = modelformset_factory(ExampleModel, extra=2)
formset = ExampleModelFormSet(queryset=ExampleModel.objects.none(),
                              initial=[{'name': 'Some Name'},
                                       {'name': 'Another Name'}])
```

Comment: By default Django's model formsets populate themselves with the results of yourmodel.objects.all(). This can be reversed with queryset=yourmodel.objects.none(), but this still doesn't allow initial values. Something about having the queryset and initial keywords set makes this not work.

Comment: How does it not work, what is it not doing? By using the updated code I get a formset from an empty queryset and initial values filled in.

Comment: Yeah.. this is the way to go. I agree.

Answer (score 1):

In Django 1.4 the rule changed: the number of initials to be displayed corresponds to "extra" parameter. 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#providing-initial-values

In my case the count of initial parameters varies dynamically, so
I found the following way:

```
initial=[{'name': 'Some Name'},{'name': 'Another Name'}]
formset = ExampleModelFormSet(queryset=ExampleModel.objects.none(),
                      initial=initial, extra=len(initial))


class MyBaseFormSet(BaseModelFormSet):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.extra = kwargs.pop('extra', self.extra)
        super(MyBaseFormSet, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

provided, ExampleModelFormSet is based on MyBaseFormSet

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution could be that you pass a form that extends a modelform() to a formset (rather than modelformset).

That way you can set initial values in the form.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this? I'm not sure I understand what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use initial argument, as with regular formsets 
http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/formsets/#using-initial-data-with-a-formset

Comment: Yes, if it was a regular formset this is possible. However this formset was generated using modelformset_factory().

Answer (score 0):

You can alter the initial data afterwards.

For example:

```
# Construct the FormSet class
ExampleFormSet = modelformset_factory(ParentModel, ChildModel)

# Set the initial data
initial_data = {'field1': 1}
for form in ExampleFormSet.extra_forms:
    for field in form.fields:
        field.initial = initial_data[field.name]
```

Comment: When I try that (with formset_factory), I get `'str' object has no attribute 'initial'`
What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: @LukasKawerau: please check what `form.fields` returns. This code might need a correction.

Comment: @LukasKawerau , in python 2.7 (at least) iterating on a dictionary gies only keys not data

Answer (score 0):

The simple way how to pass initial data with the same count of extra forms:

```
MyModelFormSet = lambda *a, **kw: modelformset_factory(MyModel, extra=kw.pop('extra', 1))(*a, **kw)
```

Usage in views:

```
initial=[{'name': 'Some Name'},{'name': 'Another Name'}
formset = MyModelFormSet(queryset=MyModel.objects.none(), initial, extra=len(initial))})
```

Answer (score 0):

Affter two days found this: http://streamhacker.com/2010/03/01/django-model-formsets/

```
def custom_field_callback(field):
    return field.formfield(required=False)

FormSet = modelformset_factory(model, formfield_callback=custom_field_callback)

def custom_field_callback(field):
    if field.name == 'optional':
        return field.formfield(required=False)
    elif field.name == 'text':
        return field.formfield(widget=Textarea)
    elif field.name == 'integer':
        return IntegerField()
    else:
        return field.formfield()
```