# django formset update existing

Tags: python, django

I want to create something similar as django admin changelist view with list_editable items...

I succeeded in creating the view. But when I post it dies on validation errors.

```
 if request.POST:
        formset_class = modelformset_factory(Job)
        formset =formset_class(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if formset.is_valid():
           formset.save()
```

The problem is that I have only a couple of attributes editable. Therefore some of them are not part of POST and model complains about them being mandatory.

But I want to UPDATE objects not create them. Basically I really want the same thing admin does when having set `list_editable` but in my own view

Comment: You also need to show how you create the formset originally during the GET.

Comment: Does this answer solve your problem? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7174617/django-set-default-value-for-formset-factory-form-element

Comment: I am using modelAdmin directly something like - 
job_admin.list_editable = ("time", "what", "approved")
cl = ChangeList(request, blabla bla...)
FormSet = job_admin.get_changelist_formset(request)
cl.formset = FormSet(queryset=cl.result_list)

And no, it does not solve it because I need fields that are filled with different values for each row. E.g. a solution would be if my formset created a hidden field for each value of the model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanted a functionality just like admin using list_editable, so I went for it and pretty much copied the code from `options.py` of django source. I retrieved admin for my object and then saved original values (function `fix_old_job_admin` sets them back)

This code solved my problem

```
job_admin = admin.site._registry[Job]
# save old values so that you can go back to them later
old_list_display = job_admin.list_display
old_list_filter = job_admin.list_filter
old_ordering = job_admin.model._meta.ordering
job_admin.list_editable = ("time", "what", "approved")
cl = ChangeList(request, job_admin.model, job_admin.list_display, job_admin.list_display_links, job_admin.list_filter, job_admin.date_hierarchy, job_admin.search_fields, job_admin.list_select_related, job_admin.list_per_page, job_admin.list_editable,job_admin.admin_site, job_admin)
# options.py from django framework lines 1181-1208 (v. 1.4) 
if request.POST:
    FormSet = job_admin.get_changelist_formset(request)
    formset =FormSet(request.POST, request.FILES, queryset=cl.result_list)
    if formset.is_valid():
        changecount = 0
        for form in formset.forms:
            if form.has_changed():
                obj = job_admin.save_form(request, form, change=True)
                job_admin.save_model(request, obj, form, change=True)
                job_admin.save_related(request, form, formsets=[], change=True)
                change_msg = job_admin.construct_change_message(request, form, None)
                job_admin.log_change(request, obj, change_msg)
                changecount += 1 

        if changecount:
            if changecount == 1:
                name = force_unicode(job_admin.model._meta.verbose_name)
            else:
                name = force_unicode(job_admin.model._meta.verbose_name_plural)
            msg = ungettext("%(count)s %(name)s was changed successfully.",
                                "%(count)s %(name)s were changed successfully.",
                                changecount) % {'count': changecount,
                                                'name': name,
                                                'obj': force_unicode(obj)}
            job_admin.message_user(request, msg)
        # call function that sets admin with original values
        fix_old_job_admin(job_admin, old_list_display, old_ordering, old_list_filter)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(request.get_full_path())


FormSet = job_admin.get_changelist_formset(request)
cl.formset = FormSet(queryset=cl.result_list)

context = Context({
    'app_label': ContentType.objects.get_for_model(Lawyer).app_label,
    'verbose_name_plural': Job._meta.verbose_name_plural.title(),
    "cl": cl,
    'request': request,

                   })
# call function that sets admin with original values
fix_old_job_admin(job_admin, old_list_display, old_ordering, old_list_filter)
return render_to_response('yourtemplate/similar_to_changelist.html', context, RequestContext(request))
```