# Django - Get input of Radio buttons in a loop

Tags: django, loops, django-forms, radio-button

I need a page for absence control, where there are looped over all users and with each user is displayed 3 radio buttons : present, absent and allowed_absent. After it is filled in for each user, it should be submitted.

This is the important part of my code:

**HTML**  baksgewijs_attendance.html

```
   <form class="createattendance-form" action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.non_field_errors }}
            {% for user in users %}
            {{ user }}
            <div class="form-group">
                <div>
                    {{ form.attendance}}
                    {{ form.attendance.errors }}
                </div>
            </div>
            {% endfor %}
            <br>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary save"> Save absence </button>
        </div>
        </form>
```

**Models.py**

```
class Attendance(models.Model):
    attendance = models.CharField(max_length=13)
    user = models.ForeignKey('puma_core.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    baksgewijs = models.ForeignKey(Baksgewijs, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.attendance
```

**forms.py**

```
attendance_choices = (
    ('absent', 'Afwezig'),
    ('allowedabsent', 'Geoorloofd afwezig'),
    ('present', 'Aanwezig'),
)


class CreateAttendance(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Attendance
        fields = ['attendance']
        widgets = {
            'attendance': forms.RadioSelect(choices=attendance_choices)
        }
```

**views.py**

```
def baksgewijs_attendance(request):
    peloton = Peloton.objects.all()
    users = User.objects.all()
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CreateAttendance(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            message = messages.success(request, ("De aanwezigheid is opgeslagen"))
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("baksgewijs_index"), {
                "message" : message
            })
        else:
            return render(request, 'baksgewijs/baksgewijs_attendance.html', {"form": CreateAttendance})
```

User.objects.all gives all user names.

**The problem is: in this way I can only select one option in total, while I want to be able to select the absence per user. How can I solve this?**

Comment: How does the attendance model relate back to the user model so you know which user attendance has been entered for?

Comment: @MikeyLockwood  in the attendance model:
user = models.ForeignKey('puma_core.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

Comment: You'll need a [ModelFormset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#model-formsets) to create more than one model at a time using django forms. You can pass your form to the formset, but the form will also need to populate the user. Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1314350/passing-initial-into-djangos-modelformset) on how to pass initial values to the formset so that the users are pre-populated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look into using a formset instead of a form:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/forms/formsets/

To give you an idea forms.py whould look something like this:

```
attendance_choices = (
    ('absent', 'Afwezig'),
    ('allowedabsent', 'Geoorloofd afwezig'),
    ('present', 'Aanwezig'),
)


class CreateAttendance(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Attendance
        fields = ['user', 'attendance']
        widgets = {
            'attendance': forms.RadioSelect(choices=attendance_choices)
        }

from django.forms import formset_factory
AttendanceFormSet = formset_factory(CreateAttendance)
```

And then the vieuws should be modified to use formsets

```
def baksgewijs_attendance(request):
    peloton = Peloton.objects.all()
    users = User.objects.all()
    if request.method == "POST":
        formset = AttendanceFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if formset.is_valid():
            formset.save()
            message = messages.success(request, ("De aanwezigheid is opgeslagen"))
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("baksgewijs_index"), {
                "message" : message
            })
        else:
            return render(request, 'baksgewijs/baksgewijs_attendance.html', {"formset": AttendanceFormSet(initial={'user': users})})
```

Comment: In my html, am I supposed to go over each formset in a for loop? Since I get an error:
KeyError at /baksgewijs/baksgewijs/createattendance
0
And the {% for form in formset %} is highlighted red.